# Python 2.x - Write binary output to stdout?

Tags: python, binary, stdout

Is there any way to write binary output to sys.stdout in Python 2.x? In Python 3.x, you can just use sys.stdout.buffer (or detach stdout, etc...), but I haven't been able to find any solutions for Python 2.5/2.6.

EDIT: I'm trying to push a PDF file (in binary form) to stdout for serving up on a web server. When I try to write the file using sys.stdout.write, it adds all sorts of carriage returns to the binary stream that causes the PDF to render corrupt.

EDIT 2: For this project, I need to run on a Windows Server, unfortunately, so Linux solutions are out.

Simply Dummy Example (reading from a file on disk, instead of generating on the fly, just so we know that the generation code isn't the issue):

```
file = open('C:\\test.pdf','rb') 
pdfFile = file.read() 
sys.stdout.write(pdfFile)
```

Comment: When you did `sys.stdout.write()` what didn't work?

Comment: See above for explanation, but the issue is basically that python adds carriage returns when it tries to convert the binary stream to a string for writing.

Comment: Does `sys.stdout = os.fdopen(1, "wb")` work for you to eliminate text-mode conversions?  (You'll still need to use sys.stdout.write if you don't want the NLs from print statements.)  (http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.fdopen)

Comment: Thanks for the great question. I learned something new today.

Comment: @Roger, surprisingly `os.fdopen` doesn't solve it, although running python with the `-u` works. `-u` does bring extra overhead though

Comment: Maybe you want to check out the [link](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65443-sending-binary-data-to-stdout-under-windows/) again, I added another answer. A wrapper for the stdout using `os.write()` and `os.read()` seems to be working fine in my test cases.

Comment: Good question; I had the same issue when I wanted to serve a PNG file from a Python script under Windows Apache.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Which platform are you on?

You could try [this recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65443-sending-binary-data-to-stdout-under-windows/) if you're on Windows (the link suggests it's Windows specific anyway).

```
if sys.platform == "win32":
    import os, msvcrt
    msvcrt.setmode(sys.stdout.fileno(), os.O_BINARY)
```

There are some references on the web that there would/should be a function in Python 3.1 to reopen `sys.stdout` in binary mode but I don't really know if there's a better alternative then the above for Python 2.x.

Comment: I did a test just reading the PDF in from a file and writing it straight back out, the carriage returns are still added.

Comment: The windows solution link you give is the perfect solution. I can't thank you enough; this was driving me absolutely up the wall.

Comment: Great! The same works for [`stdin`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28673339/321973) as well, and both is required to make e.g. a functional `cat` clone that can handle binary files

Answer (score 10):

You can use unbuffered mode: `python -u script.py`.

```
-u     Force  stdin,  stdout  and stderr to be totally unbuffered.
       On systems where it matters, also put stdin, stdout and stderr
       in binary mode.
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use [argopen](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/argopen).argopen(), it handles dash as stdin/stdout, and fixes binary mode on Windows.

```
import argopen
stdout = argopen.argopen('-', 'wb')
stdout.write(some_binary_data)
```

Comment: This is much neater than the ActiveState recipe. How did you figure it out? The module is barely documented.

Comment: Didn't work for me -- my distro doesn't have argopen.  Didn't want to install it since "msvcrt.setmode()" mentioned above worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

In Python 2.x, all strings are binary character arrays by default, so I believe you should be able to just

```
>>> sys.stdout.write(data)
```

EDIT: I've confirmed your experience.

I created one file, gen_bytes.py

```
import sys
for char in range(256):
    sys.stdout.write(chr(char))
```

And another read_bytes.py

```
import subprocess
import sys

proc = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, 'gen_bytes.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
res = proc.wait()
bytes = proc.stdout.read()
if not len(bytes) == 256:
    print 'Received incorrect number of bytes: {0}'.format(len(bytes))
    raise SystemExit(1)
if not map(ord, bytes) == range(256):
    print 'Received incorrect bytes: {0}'.format(map(ord, bytes))
    raise SystemExit(2)
print "Everything checks out"
```

Put them in the same directory and run read_bytes.py. Sure enough, it appears as if Python is in fact converting newlines on output. I suspect this only happens on a Windows OS.

```
> .\read_bytes.py
Received incorrect number of bytes: 257
```

Following the lead by ChristopheD, and changing gen_bytes to the following corrects the issue.

```
import sys

if sys.platform == "win32":
    import os, msvcrt
    msvcrt.setmode(sys.stdout.fileno(), os.O_BINARY)

for char in range(256):
    sys.stdout.write(chr(char))
```

I include this for completeness. ChristopheD deserves the credit.

Comment: This works if you're only trying to add string data, but python tries to stringify binary data when just calling write, corrupting the data.

Comment: I ran your `gen_bytes.py` and `read_bytes.py` on Mac OS X (Python 2.5 with minor modifications for the missing "format" keywords) and it "Everything checks out"

Comment: It looks like it's a Windows-only issue.

Comment: On windows, I found that just running `gen_bytes.py > bytes.bin` I could see that the file was 257 bytes simply by doing a `dir`

Comment: Unless you're using powershell, in which case `gen_bytes.py > bytes.bin` generates a unicode-encoded file of 522 bytes.

Comment: If I reverse the two processes, such that the parent writes and child reads, then I have to set sys.stdin to be binary, *on the child*. Perhaps the PIPEs that subprocess sets up are always binary, but stdin/stdout are not?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using a wrapper for a file-descriptor. (Tested in Python 3.2.5 on Cygwin)

```
class BinaryFile(object):
    ''' Wraps a file-descriptor to binary read/write. The wrapped
    file can not be closed by an instance of this class, it must
    happen through the original file.

    :param fd: A file-descriptor (integer) or file-object that
        supports the ``fileno()`` method. '''

    def __init__(self, fd):
        super(BinaryFile, self).__init__()
        fp = None
        if not isinstance(fd, int):
            fp = fd
            fd = fp.fileno()
        self.fd = fd
        self.fp = fp

    def fileno(self):
        return self.fd

    def tell(self):
        if self.fp and hasattr(self.fp, 'tell'):
            return self.fp.tell()
        else:
            raise io.UnsupportedOperation(
                'can not tell position from file-descriptor')

    def seek(self, pos, how=os.SEEK_SET):
        try:
            return os.lseek(self.fd, pos, how)
        except OSError as exc:
            raise io.UnsupportedOperation('file-descriptor is not seekable')

    def write(self, data):
        if not isinstance(data, bytes):
            raise TypeError('must be bytes, got %s' % type(data).__name__)
        return os.write(self.fd, data)

    def read(self, length=None):
        if length is not None:
            return os.read(self.fd, length)
        else:
            result = b''
            while True:
                data = self.read(1024)
                if not data:
                    break
                result += data
            return result
```

Comment: The code in this answer doesn't solve the problem in Python 2.7: the `\r` bytes still appear on standard output on Windows. By adding `msvcrt.setmode(self.fd, os.O_BINARY)` (as indicated in other answers), the `\r` bytes disappear.