# problem with closing python pypdf - writing. getting a valueError: I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python, pypdf

can't figure this up
this function (part of class for scraping internet site into a pdf) supposed to merge the pdf file generated from web pages  using pypdf.

this is the method code:

```
def mergePdf(self,mainname,inputlist=0):
    """merging the pdf pages
    getting an inputlist to merge or defaults to the class instance self.pdftomerge list"""
    from pyPdf import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
    self._mergelist = inputlist or self.pdftomerge
    self.pdfoutput = PdfFileWriter()

    for name in self._mergelist:
        print "merging %s into main pdf file: %s" % (name,mainname)
        self._filestream = file(name,"rb")
        self.pdfinput = PdfFileReader(self._filestream)
        for p in self.pdfinput.pages:
            self.pdfoutput.addPage(p)
        self._filestream.close()

    self._pdfstream = file(mainname,"wb")
    self._pdfstream.open()
    self.pdfoutput.write(self._pdfstream)
    self._pdfstream.close()
```

I keep getting this error:

```
  File "c:\tmp\easy_install-iik9vj\pyPdf-1.13-py2.7-win32.egg.tmp\pyPdf\pdf.py", line 264, in write
    self._sweepIndirectReferences(externalReferenceMap, self._root)
  File "c:\tmp\easy_install-iik9vj\pyPdf-1.13-py2.7-win32.egg.tmp\pyPdf\pdf.py", line 339, in _sweepIndirectReferences
    self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, realdata)
  File "c:\tmp\easy_install-iik9vj\pyPdf-1.13-py2.7-win32.egg.tmp\pyPdf\pdf.py", line 315, in _sweepIndirectReferences
    value = self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, value)
  File "c:\tmp\easy_install-iik9vj\pyPdf-1.13-py2.7-win32.egg.tmp\pyPdf\pdf.py", line 339, in _sweepIndirectReferences
    self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, realdata)
  File "c:\tmp\easy_install-iik9vj\pyPdf-1.13-py2.7-win32.egg.tmp\pyPdf\pdf.py", line 315, in _sweepIndirectReferences
    value = self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, value)
  File "c:\tmp\easy_install-iik9vj\pyPdf-1.13-py2.7-win32.egg.tmp\pyPdf\pdf.py", line 324, in _sweepIndirectReferences
    value = self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, data[i])
  File "c:\tmp\easy_install-iik9vj\pyPdf-1.13-py2.7-win32.egg.tmp\pyPdf\pdf.py", line 339, in _sweepIndirectReferences
    self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, realdata)
  File "c:\tmp\easy_install-iik9vj\pyPdf-1.13-py2.7-win32.egg.tmp\pyPdf\pdf.py", line 315, in _sweepIndirectReferences
    value = self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, value)
  File "c:\tmp\easy_install-iik9vj\pyPdf-1.13-py2.7-win32.egg.tmp\pyPdf\pdf.py", line 345, in _sweepIndirectReferences
    newobj = data.pdf.getObject(data)
  File "c:\tmp\easy_install-iik9vj\pyPdf-1.13-py2.7-win32.egg.tmp\pyPdf\pdf.py", line 645, in getObject
    self.stream.seek(start, 0)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

but when I check the status of self._pdfstream I get:

```
<open file 'c:\python27\learn\dive.pdf', mode 'wb' at 0x013B2020>
```

what am I doing wrong?

i'll be glad for any help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, I found your problem. You were right to call `file()`. Don't try to call `open()` at all.

Your problem is the **input** file still needs to be open when you call `self.pdfoutput.write(self._pdfstream)`, so you need to remove the line `self._filestream.close()`.

Edit: This script will trigger the problem. The first write will succeed and the second will fail.

```
from pyPdf import PdfFileReader as PfR, PdfFileWriter as PfW

input_filename = 'in.PDF' # replace with a real file
output_filename = 'out.PDF' # something that doesn't exist

infile = file(input_filename, 'rb')
reader = PfR(infile)
writer = PfW()

writer.addPage(reader.getPage(0))
outfile = file(output_filename, 'wb')
writer.write(outfile)
print "First Write Successful!"
infile.close()
outfile.close()

infile = file(input_filename, 'rb')
reader = PfR(infile)
writer = PfW()

writer.addPage(reader.getPage(0))
outfile = file(output_filename, 'wb')
infile.close() # BAD!

writer.write(outfile)
print "You'll get an IOError Before this line"
outfile.close()
```

Comment: hey agf, as I wrote my problem is with self._pdfstream. I changed to open, but this doesn't help. I still get the error when i try to do write from the pypdf and when I check the object I still get - <open file 'c:\python27\learn\dive.pdf', mode 'wb' at 0x013B2020>. wtf?!

Comment: @alonisser You're right, calling `open()` was wrong! But your problem isn't with `self._pdfstream`, it's with the input streams. Editing my answer.

Comment: this seems to solve the problem - thanks alot! but now there is another problem! i get the same long error string and a different end: line 693, in readObjectHeader
    return int(idnum), int(generation)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' any ideas

Comment: It sounds like one of your PDFs has a field that is supposed to be an integer, but isn't. Beyond that, you might have to dig in to the pyPdf source to figure out the problem.

Comment: ok - I solved this. seems like the problem was with caliing pypdf to add pages to a file that already exists - changing the name of the output file to something like "output.pdf" solved this .  thanka again @agf for all the help.

Comment: I was able to put this answer to use. I still use `open` instead of `file`, but I save all my open file objects and only close them at the very end.