# Plot/combine multiple pdf files as one single pdf file in matplotlib (python) or LaTeX

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib, latex, subplot

I have five pdf files with high resolution. I do not want to crop each file and put them together as a single because I would like to keep that high quality images (pdf) so is there a way for me to merge those 5 pdf files:

map1.pdf

map2.pdf

map3.pdf

map4.pdf

map5.pdf

And save them as a single ONE pdf file? Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "merge"? Do you want a separate page for each input file, or do you want to somehow arrange them all on a single page? What platform are you using?

Comment: @ ali_m: no, I have five different maps and would like to merge/combine those five pdf files as a single one file so I can use/plot in my writing.

Comment: Based on your response I assume that you want an output PDF containing a single page. There are an infinite number of ways to position five different images on a single page. If you want to do this programatically then you will need to be more specific about your inputs and your desired output.

Comment: Does "high resolution" imply that the PDF files actually contain bitmapped images?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want to combine several pdf-files in a single pdf-file. Right?
There are several ways of doing this:

- Under Linux you can do this with `pdftk` (maybe you have to install it first:)

  `pdftk map1.pdf map2.pdf map3.pdf map4.pdf map5.pdf cat output newfile.pdf`

**Update**: I Just saw there is even a Windows version of pdftk which comes with a nice GUI (if you do not like the command line): [PDFtk for Windows](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/)

- There are several free online services which offer merging multiple pdf-files. (see, for example, http://www.pdfmerge.com/)
- Need a cross-platform solution? Then have a look at [Apache's PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/):

  > This application will take a list of pdf documents and merge them, saving the result in a new document.
  >   usage: `java -jar pdfbox-app-x.y.z.jar PDFMerger <Source PDF files (2 ..n)> <Target PDF file>`
- Using python? Have a look at the answers to [this SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444645/merge-pdf-files), which suggests using [pyPDF](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyPdf) and shows you how to use it.

Comment: @ F.Knorr: I do not have Linux so have no idea and yes, you are right. I want to combine several pdf files .

Answer (score 0):

In LaTeX you can use the [`pdfpages`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) package. (It is included in the TeXLive distribution.)