# How to stitch two pdf pages into one in python

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I am using python, and I want to combine two PDF pages into a single page.  My purpose is to combine these two pages into one, not two PDFs.  Is there any way to combine the two PDFs one by one?  I don't want to merge these two. Without overlapping, is there any way to combine them?

Comment: Did you see that [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444645/merge-pdf-files) to inspire you some solutions?

Comment: With what I have, I would perhaps turn them into images with python, then join them in Inkscape and then export it to a PDF file.

Answer (score 7):

If I understood you correctly, you want to stitch two pages this way:

```
---------
|   |   |
| 1 | 2 |
|   |   |
---------
```

The pyPDF3 module allows you to do this.

```py
from PyPDF3 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
from PyPDF3.pdf import PageObject

pdf_filenames = ["out_mitry.pdf", "out_cdg.pdf"]

input1 = PdfFileReader(open(pdf_filenames[0], "rb"), strict=False)
input2 = PdfFileReader(open(pdf_filenames[1], "rb"), strict=False)

page1 = input1.getPage(0)
page2 = input2.getPage(0)

total_width = page1.mediaBox.upperRight[0] + page2.mediaBox.upperRight[0]
total_height = max([page1.mediaBox.upperRight[1], page2.mediaBox.upperRight[1]])

new_page = PageObject.createBlankPage(None, total_width, total_height)

# Add first page at the 0,0 position
new_page.mergePage(page1)
# Add second page with moving along the axis x
new_page.mergeTranslatedPage(page2, page1.mediaBox.upperRight[0], 0)

output = PdfFileWriter()
output.addPage(new_page)
output.write(open("result.pdf", "wb"))
```

Answer (score 1):

PyPDF version 3.16 has updated methods so updating the answer provided by @Alexander Nikitin.

```
from pypdf import PdfWriter, PdfReader, PageObject

pdf_filenames = ["out_mitry.pdf", "out_cdg.pdf"]

input1 = PdfReader(open(pdf_filenames[0], "rb"), strict=False)
input2 = PdfReader(open(pdf_filenames[1], "rb"), strict=False)

page1 = input1.getPage(0)
page2 = input2.getPage(0)

total_width = page1.mediabox.right + page2.mediabox.right
total_height = max([page1.mediabox.top, page2.mediabox.top])

new_page = PageObject.create_blank_page(None, total_width, total_height)

# Add first page at the 0,0 position
new_page.merge_page(page1)
# Add second page with moving along the axis x
new_page.merge_translated_page(page2, page1.mediabox.right, 0)

output = PdfWriter()
output.add_page(new_page)
output.write(open("result.pdf", "wb"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use module **PyPDF2** (https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/).

Example:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger
pdf_list = ['/path/to/first.pdf', '/path/to/second.pdf']
merger = PdfFileMerger()

for i in pdf_list:
    merger.append(open(i, 'rb'))

with open('/path/to/save/new.pdf', 'wb') as fout:
    merger.write(fout)
```

Comment: I have only one pdf.  I need to combine two pages of a single pdf into one page

Comment: what do you mean combine 2 pages of pdf into 1 page ?! 
I can see one reason why you would do that, which is if you have one empty page.
I haven't tried this, but I think you can merge the content if you use the `from io import BytesIO` and then read the content of your pdfs, append it to a list, then write the bytes with `PdfWriter()`