# how to combine all the files of one directory of one extension into one folder

Tags: python, operating-system

how can i combine all PDF files of one directory (this pdfs can be on different deep of directory) into one new folder?

i have been tried this:

```
new_root = r'C:\Users\me\new_root'
root_with_files = r'C:\Users\me\all_of_my_pdf_files\'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root_with_files):
    for file in files:
        os.path.join(new_root, file)
```

but it's doest add anything to my folder

Comment: I think join doesn't work like that. Maybe you should try the function from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444645/merge-pdf-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
import shutil

new_root = r'C:\Users\me\new_root'
root_with_files = r'C:\Users\me\all_of_my_pdf_files'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root_with_files):
    for file in files:
        if file.lower().endswith('.pdf') :  # .pdf files only
            shutil.copy( os.path.join(root, file), new_root )
```

Comment: by the way if i want all files i guess i dont need `lower()` ?

Comment: ok, `lower` is not checking only lower files, thanks, this is right

Comment: @germanjke sorry about the typo. fixed now. thanks for spotting it =)

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't move any files to new folder. you can move your files using `os.replace(src,dst)`.

try this:

```
new_root = r'C:\Users\me\new_root'
root_with_files = r'C:\Users\me\all_of_my_pdf_files\'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root_with_files):
    for file in files:
        os.replace(os.path.join(root, file),os.path.join(new_root, file))
```

Comment: but i have an empy new foler `new_root` so i dont have anything to replace can i just add files?

Comment: Yes, you can. `os.replace(src,dst)` will move your file. If `dst` exists, it will be replaced,