# Merging PDF files starting with similar names in a directory

Tags: python, merge, pypdf

I have several PDF files located in a folder on my Desktop called *Highlighted* and stored the path of this directory into a variable called `filePath`.

Given a list of actor names called `actorList`, I want to **merge** all the PDFs **starting with similar names** (e.g., **Adam, Sandler**) in the `filePath` directory, separately (please see the **image** below).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e34lR.png)

```
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger

actorList = ['Adam, Sandler', 'Daniel, Craig', 'Jennifer, Aniston']
filePath  = r'C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\Highlighted' + '\\'
fileList  = []

for actorName in actorList:
   for path, currentDirectory, files in os.walk(filePath):
      for fileName in files:
         if fileName.startswith(actorName):
            fileList.append(fileName)

# Append & Merge all PDFs starting with similar names 
merger = PdfFileMerger()
for actorName in actorList:
    for fileName in fileList:
        if actorName not in fileName:
            continue
        merger.append(filePath + fileName)
    merger.write(filePath + actorName + '.pdf')
    merger.close()
```

I have tried all methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444645/merge-pdf-files), but had no luck! Any thoughts please??

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved after moving the `merger` inside the outer `for` loop. I was getting the `NoneType` error, because the `merger` was not initialized after each time it was getting closed by `merger.close()`.

```
# merger = PdfFileMerger()   =====> move the PdfFileMerger() from OUTSIDE
    for actorName in actorList:                                       
        merger = PdfFileMerger() # <===== to INSIDE
        for fileName in fileList:
            if actorName not in fileName:
                continue
            merger.append(filePath + fileName)
        merger.write(filePath + actorName + '.pdf')
        merger.close()
```