# Python: How to print 2 pages of pdf into one sheet of paper using Python

Tags: python

I have pdf which have same paper size (A6) and multiple pages. What i want to do is to print 2 pages into one sheet of paper (A4) using python. Try to automate thing here which is why i use Python.

I know i can print stuff using GSPrint with Python but i never quite get how to do this with it.

```
import win32print
import win32api
import autoit
import os

dir_print = r'C:\Users\anom\Google Drive\Programming\test\New folder'
list_tracking = os.listdir(dir_print)

for name in list_tracking:
    print('Printing - ', name)
    GHOSTSCRIPT_PATH = r"C:\Users\anom\Google Drive\Programming\test\GHOSTSCRIPT\bin\gswin32.exe"
    GSPRINT_PATH = r"C:\Users\anom\Google Drive\Programming\test\GSPRINT\gsprint.exe"
    filename = os.path.join(dir_print, name)
    win32api.ShellExecute(0, 'open', GSPRINT_PATH, '-ghostscript "'+GHOSTSCRIPT_PATH+'" -printer "RICOH SP 150SU" -color -dPDFFitPage "'+filename+'"', '.', 0)
```

Its got me thinking to resize the page to A4 first then print which is doable with Pypdf2 module (maybe...) But i stuck at printing 2 pages into one sheet of paper.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444645/merge-pdf-files

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge PDF files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444645/merge-pdf-files)

Comment: Sorry but nope. I try to print a pdf that have 2 pages. The problem is, i only want to print this 2 pages using only one sheet of paper

Comment: The problem is NOT merging pdfs. The problem is to merge 2 pages into one pages and send it to printer to print it.

Comment: You can extract 2 pages, merge them into one, and the print the output file.

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: Reading the docs can help.

Comment: http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/pythondoc-pyPdf.pdf.html

Answer (score -1):

Here you go... for both A5 (two per page) and A6 (4 per page)
You'll need to pip install Pillow

```
import fitz
from fpdf import FPDF
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

def pixmap_to_image(pixmap):
    img_data = pixmap.samples
    img = Image.frombytes("RGB", [pixmap.width, pixmap.height], img_data)
    return img

input_pdf_path = "C:\\input folder path\\input file.pdf"
output_4_per_page = "C:\\input folder path\\output file A6.pdf"
output_2_per_page_landscape = "C:\\input folder path\\output file A5.pdf"

# Read the original PDF
doc = fitz.open(input_pdf_path)

# Create 4 sheets per page
pdf_4_per_page = FPDF()
for i in range(0, len(doc), 4):
    pdf_4_per_page.add_page()
    for j in range(4):
        page_idx = i + j
        if page_idx < len(doc):
            pixmap = doc.load_page(page_idx).get_pixmap()
            img = pixmap_to_image(pixmap)
            buffer = BytesIO()
            img.save(buffer, format="PNG")
            buffer.seek(0)
            x_offset = (j % 2) * 105
            y_offset = (j // 2) * 148.5
            pdf_4_per_page.image(buffer, x=x_offset, y=y_offset, w=105, h=148.5)
pdf_4_per_page.output(output_4_per_page)

# Create 2 sheets per page in landscape
pdf_2_per_page_landscape = FPDF(orientation="L", unit="mm", format="A4")  # A4 landscape
for i in range(0, len(doc), 2):
    pdf_2_per_page_landscape.add_page()
    for j in range(2):
        page_idx = i + j
        if page_idx < len(doc):
            pixmap = doc.load_page(page_idx).get_pixmap()
            img = pixmap_to_image(pixmap)
            buffer = BytesIO()
            img.save(buffer, format="PNG")
            buffer.seek(0)
            x_offset = j * 148.5  # Half of A4 width in mm
            y_offset = 0
            pdf_2_per_page_landscape.image(buffer, x=x_offset, y=y_offset, w=148.5, h=210)  # A5 size in landscape
pdf_2_per_page_landscape.output(output_2_per_page_landscape)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).