# Merge PDFs having Digital Signature, in Python

Tags: python, pdf, digital-signature, pypdf

I am tying to merge 1500-1600 PDFs. Thanks to below link, I got a code to merge PDFs in python.

[Merge PDF files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444645/merge-pdf-files)

However, it is resulting in a empty file, probably because there are digital signatures in the PDFs I am combining.

Can someone suggest a way to combine these files having digital signatures? I do not mind losing digital signature in the output file.
(It is also ok, if there is a way to remove digital signatures from the source files and then combine them)

Code:

```
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger

os.chdir("C:\\test")

x = [a for a in os.listdir() if a.endswith(".pdf")]

merger = PdfFileMerger()

for pdf in x:
    pdfobject = open(pdf, 'rb')
    merger.append(pdfobject)
    pdfobject.close()
    
merger.write("result.pdf")
merger.close()
```

Comment: Most likely this is not related to the digital signatures.

Comment: Why did you modify this last line in the solution `with open("result.pdf", "wb") as fout:
    merger.write(fout)`

Answer (score 0):

This code, using pypdf, works for me using signed and non-signed PDF files:

```py
import os
from pypdf import PdfReader, PdfWriter

files = [fn for fn in os.listdir() if fn.endswith(".pdf")]

writer = PdfWriter()

for pdf in files:
    with open(pdf, 'rb') as f:
        reader = PdfReader(f)
        writer.append(reader)

writer.write("result.pdf")
```