# Concat PDF files

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, pdf-generation

I have a number of pdf file and I'd like to concat them into one pdf.

I'm using **Python 3**

(I've seen *PyPDF2* but last version was released in 2016, so i'm worried about upgrading in the future)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge PDF files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444645/merge-pdf-files)

Comment: My question was more about PyPDF versionning and why the last stable version was released 6 year ago

Comment: Then try the bumped verion of PyPDF2 which is PyPDF3
https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF3/#history

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used PyPDF2 without any problem with Python 3.7.9.
[Merge PDF files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444645/merge-pdf-files) File Concatenation answer by Paul Rooney helped me