# How can I merge two PDF files without overlapping content

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, pdfrw

Using another stackoverflow question & answer, I was able to locate code which partially resolves what I am trying to do [Merge PDF files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444645/merge-pdf-files).

However, this modified code results in the contents of two PDFs overlapping each outer.  I am trying to stack them or vertically concatenate the results:

Example:

- PDF1 Contents -> "Hello World"
- PDF2 Contents -> "I am Bill"

Code below results in the following overlapping image:

- [image: Invalid Result]

Desired results would look as follows:

- [image: Desired Result]

Code Used resulting in overlapping imge:

```
import pdfrw
dirPATH = r'c:\users\<username>\projects\concat_pdfs'
pdf1 = os.path.join(dirPATH, 'PDF1.pdf')
pdf2 = os.path.join(dirPATH, 'PDF2.pdf')

def concat_pdfs(pdf1, pdf2, output):
    form = pdfrw.PdfReader(pdf1)
    olay = pdfrw.PdfReader(pdf2)
    
    for form_page, overlay_page in zip(form.pages, olay.pages):
        merge_obj = pdfrw.PageMerge()
        overlay = merge_obj.add(overlay_page)[0]
        pdfrw.PageMerge(form_page).add(overlay).render()
        
    writer = pdfrw.PdfWriter()
    writer.write(output, form)
    
concat_pdfs(section1, section2, 'result.pdf')
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried

```
def combine_pdfs(dir_path1, dir_path2, save_path):
    pdf1 = pdfrw.PdfReader(dir_path1)
    pdf2 = pdfrw.PdfReader(dir_path2)
    pdf_writer = pdfrw.PdfWriter()
    for page in pdf1.pages:
        pdf_writer.addpage(page)
    for page in pdf2.pages:
        pdf_writer.addpage(page)
    pdf_writer.write(save_path)
```

Comment: When running this code, it produces the same overlapping results that I currently get.  Looking to have the text appear on page as non-overlapping (two separate lines).  Thank you though.

Comment: I used the function to merge two pdfs and it was successful without getting an overlap. How are you creating your pdf?

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example using [PyPDF2](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/) library:

```
  merger = PdfFileMerger()
  for filename in files:
    f = files[filename]
    loc = "/tmp/" + secure_filename(filename).replace(".pdf", "") + "_" + str(time.time()) + ".pdf"
    f.save(loc)
    f.close()
    reader = PdfFileReader(loc, "rb")
    merger.append(reader)
  dest = "/tmp/merged_" + str(time.time()) + ".pdf"
  merger.write(dest)
```

Here is another using [pike pdf](https://github.com/pikepdf/pikepdf):

```
  pdf = Pdf.new()
  for filename in files:
    f = files[filename]
    loc = "/tmp/" + secure_filename(filename).replace(".pdf", "") + "_" + str(time.time()) + ".pdf"
    f.save(loc)
    f.close()
    reader = Pdf.open(loc)
    pdf.pages.extend(reader.pages)
  dest = "/tmp/merged_" + str(time.time()) + ".pdf"
  pdf.save(dest)
```

Imports might look something like:

```
import time
import pdfkit
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from pikepdf import Pdf
```

Comment: Both of these pieces of code merge each PDF onto its own page of a new PDF.  I am needing to merge content onto a single PDF Page.   Contents of PDF1 (New line character) + Contents of PDF2.  With no page break...