# Is there a way to save excel worksheets as PDFs in Python without using win32.client?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am looking to save multiple excel worksheets as a PDF and then merge them all into one.

I need to do this without win32.client - is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save an excel file as a pdf, you can use asposecells and jpype:

```
import jpype
import asposecells
jpype.startJVM()
from asposecells.api import Workbook, FileFormatType, PdfSaveOptions

workbook = Workbook("example.xlsx")
saveOptions = PdfSaveOptions()
saveOptions.setOnePagePerSheet(True)
workbook.save("example.pdf", saveOptions)

jpype.shutdownJVM()
```

You can find more information here:
https://pypi.org/project/aspose-cells/

In order to merge pdf's with python you can use PyPdf2's PdfMerger:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger
pdfs = ['file1.pdf', 'file2.pdf', 'file3.pdf', 'file4.pdf']

merger = PdfFileMerger()

for pdf in pdfs:
    merger.append(pdf)

merger.write("result.pdf")
merger.close()
```

You can read more about this in this post:
[Merge PDF files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444645/merge-pdf-files)

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if there is a way to remove the "Evaluation Only. Created with Aspose.Cells for Python via Java.Copyright 2003 - 2022 Aspose Pty Ltd." from the PDF files that this creates?

Comment: Hi, I hope this will help you: https://forum.aspose.com/t/evaluation-only-does-not-go-away/135652

Comment: If you want to use Aspose.Cells without evaluation warning and  version limitations, you need  to have license to use it with full capacity. Please refer to document (https://docs.aspose.com/cells/java/licensing/) for your reference.

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose