# Merge PDF files by each folder

Tags: python, image, pdf, fpdf

This Python script is Creates PDF file from List of Images.
( It have a series of folders inside a parent one. Each folder has several images)

My current problem is,

1. all image files contained in each folder merged by folder and save(creates) as a PDf file.
2. the merged file save it as a single PDf
3. the name of pdf files is by each folder name.

Example))

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldRHC.png)

- Root(Current) Folder

Folder1 : FileA.tif , FileB.gif

Folder2 : FileC.tif

Folder2 : FileD.tif

- Result Folder

Folder1.pdf (Contains FileA.tif and FileB.gif combined into one pdf)

Folder2.pdf (Contains FileC.tif as pdf)

Folder3.pdf (Contains Filed.tif as pdf)

((MY Python script))

```
import os   
import re    
from fpdf import FPDF    
import img2pdf

pdf = FPDF()   
imagelist = [] 
 
TDPath = "D:\\Data\\ToDo"  #Root(Current) Folder
RPath = "D:\\Data\\Result" #Result Folder
      
# Image to PDF
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(TDPath):  
    for filename in [f for f in filenames if re.match('.*([.]jpg|[.]png|[.]tif|[.]gif|[.]jpeg|[.]bmp|[.]jpg)', f)]:
        full_path = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
        imagelist.append(full_path)
imagelist.sort() 

#Image to PDF
for image in imagelist:   
    pdf.add_page()    
    pdf.image(image, 0, 0, 200)


# Save the pdf file
pdf.output(TDPath+".pdf", "F")   
print("\nFound " + str(len(imagelist)) + " image files. Converting to PDF....\n")
```

Comment: Have a look at similar question here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444645/merge-pdf-files)

Comment: The ImageMagick command line tool can do this without programming.