# How can I convert multiple PDF pages into one using Python?

Tags: python

I am looking for a script that will allow me to convert several PDF pages into one so that I can read them with an AI. It is important that the text is still copyable and not e.g. an image.

I have already tried several scripts, but nothing works

Comment: a simple google query reveals [Merge PDF files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444645/merge-pdf-files), is that what you're looking for? If not, please have another look at [ask] and provide a [mre] that clarifies the specific question.

Comment: Isn't it just a matter of setting the page size to something ridiculous like 30cm x 300 metres!!! and then copying the text of the original pdf file?

Comment: @FObersteiner This is not about PDF files, this is about PDF pages. Please read my question correctly!

Comment: @k314159 But how do I script it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The following code example might be the thing you're looking for. It uses [Spire.PDF for Python](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/pdf-for-python.html) to horizontally merge multiple pages from a PDF into a single larger page in a new PDF.

```
from spire.pdf.common import *
from spire.pdf import *

# Load a PDF file
pdf = PdfDocument("File.pdf")

# Get the page width and page height of the loaded PDF
pageWidth = pdf.PageSettings.Width
pageHeight = pdf.PageSettings.Height

# Specify the start index and end index of the pages to be merged
startPageIndex = 0
endPageIndex = 1

# Create a new PDF file
newPdf = PdfDocument()

# Create a new page width that is the sum of the widths of the pages to be merged
newPageWidth = pageWidth * (endPageIndex - startPageIndex + 1)

# Add a new page with the new page width and the same page height to the new PDF file
newPage = newPdf.Pages.Add(SizeF(newPageWidth, pageHeight), PdfMargins(0.0))

# Specify the initial x and y coordinates
x = 0.0
y = 0.0

# Loop through the pages to be merged in the loaded PDF
for i in range(startPageIndex, endPageIndex + 1):
    page = pdf.Pages[i]
    # Draw the content of each page on a specific location of the new page of the new PDF file
    newPage.Canvas.DrawTemplate(page.CreateTemplate(), PointF(x, y))
    # Change the x coordinate
    x += pageWidth

# Save the new PDF file to a specific path
newPdf.SaveToFile("MergePdfPagesIntoOnePage.pdf")

pdf.Close()
newPdf.Close()
```

You can find more details in this blog post: [Merge PDF Files or Pages into One with Python](https://medium.com/@alice.yang_10652/merge-pdf-files-or-pages-into-one-with-python-301b1bbdaf7e)