# file.write() and sys.stdout.write() are giving me two different outputs - Python

Tags: python, file-io, stdout

The code below takes a JPEG image and converts it to a string. That string is then saved into the `image` variable. Then, the string is written to `a.jpg` using File IO and then written to `b.jpg` by me piping stdout to the file.

```
import thumb
import sys

x = thumb.Thumbnail('test.jpg')
x.generate(56, 56)

image = str(x)

with open('a.jpg', 'wb') as f:
    # saving to a.jpg
    f.write(image)

# saving to b.jpg
sys.stdout.write(image)
```

Usage:

```
python blah.py > b.jpg
```

This results in two image files (a.jpg and b.jpg). These images should be identical... But they aren't.

[a.jpg](http://codepad.org/tnFbfDK2)
[b.jpg](http://codepad.org/h25w3sHa)

I can see, by looking at each image in Notepad, that linebreaks are, somehow, being added to b.jpg. Resulting in a corrupted image.

Why is a.jpg different to b.jpg?

Comment: sys.stdout.mode is 'w', I think.  See, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374427/python-2-x-write-binary-output-to-stdout

Comment: Your shell is probably interpreting your output when you redirect it through standard out. Are you on linux? Using bash?

Comment: @DSM: You should post that as an answer.

Comment: The unix tendency to use stdout to communicate between programs is a BAD idea for binary data. Pleas do not do it. Running your software without redirecting to a file will mess up the terminal, etc. Do **not** do it. Please!

Comment: @Lennart: It's actually writing to my web browser. It's a CGI script. I used stdout as an example as it had the same problem and was simpler to describe :}

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, CGI is indeed an example of this very bad pattern in Unix.

Answer (score 2):

You write your data to `a.jpg` as binary, while `b.jpg` get written in text mode. When in binary mode otherwise special characters (such as newlines or EOF marker) are not treated special, while in text mode they are.

In Python 3 you can switch modes:

- http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/sys.html#sys.stdin

> The standard streams are in text mode by default. To write or read binary data to these, use the underlying binary buffer. For example, to write bytes to stdout, use sys.stdout.buffer.write(b'abc').

---

Untested (Python 2):

```
import sys, os

binout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'wb')
binout.write(b'Binary#Data...')
```

Comment: Under pep8 imports are on separate lines