# print tar.gz to stdout in python

Tags: python, gzip, tar

I can create a .tar.gz file using

```
with tarfile.open(archive, 'w:gz') as archive_fd:
    add_files_to_tar('.', archive_fd)
```

and this works fine. But sometimes I want to print these files to `stdout` (if I execute the command via SSH)

Does anyone have an idea how to do this? My old bash code is something like this

```
tar -czf - $files >&1
```

or

```
tar -czf - $files >/filename
```

Comment: What is `add_files_to_tar`?

Comment: a method to add a file to the archive.

You can replace this with

    archive_fd.add('filename')

Answer (score 2):

I *think* you can just open the tar file in streaming mode and pass it sys.stdout:

```
import sys
with tarfile.open(fileobj=sys.stdout, mode='w|gz') as archive_fd:
    add_files_to_tar('.', archive_fd)
```

The tarfile documentation says that this doesn't close stdout when it finishes.

Answer (score 1):

Use `fileobj=sys.stdout` and the pipe symbol (to indicate streaming mode) in the mode string.

This is similar to `tar czf - .`:

```
with tarfile.open(archive, 'w|gz', fileobj=sys.stdout) as archive_fd:
    archive_fd.add('.')
```

This is tested on Linux; I assume it will fail on Windows. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374427/python-2-x-write-binary-output-to-stdout) for a solution to that problem.

References:

- [Python 2.x - Write binary output to stdout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374427/python-2-x-write-binary-output-to-stdout)
- http://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.open

Comment: Thanks, it works fine for me (on linux):)
thanks for the reference links

Comment: You are welcome. Please remember to vote for the answers you found useful and to accept the answer that solved your problem.