# Download image by Python CGI

Tags: python, image, svg, http-headers, cgi

I have a Python cgi that converts a svg to a png file, I'd like then to download the converted output to the user's disk.

```
#the conversion stuff
print "Content-Type: image/png"
print "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='pythonchart.png'"
print
print open("http:\\localhost\myproj\pythonchart.png").read()
```

This results in a png file containing `‰PNG`.

Any help please?

Comment: Do you actually have a file on your filesystem named `"http:\\localhost\myproj\pythonchart.png"`? Because `open()` doesn't do HTTP, but your reported error message doesn't match what you *should* be getting.

Comment: I changed the file path to the location of my project : "C:\wamp\www\myproj\pythonchart.png" and I still get the same error

Comment: I have also tried @teferi suggestion but still the same problem :(

Comment: Can you confirm through other means that `C:\wamp\www\myproj\pythonchart.png` actually exists and is a valid PNG file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading binary data from the text-mode stream returned by `open()`, and writing binary data to the text-mode stdout stream. You must open the file in binary mode, and convert the stdout to binary mode.

```
import sys
print "Content-Type: image/png"
print "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='pythonchart.png'"
print

if sys.platform == "win32":
    import os, msvcrt
    msvcrt.setmode(sys.stdout.fileno(), os.O_BINARY)
print open("C:\\wamp\\www\\myproj\\pythonchart.png", "rb").read()
```

Ref: [Python 2.x - Write binary output to stdout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374427/python-2-x-write-binary-output-to-stdout)

Comment: Thanks! what if i'm on Linux RedHat ?

Comment: Then trying to open `C:\\wamp\\www\\myproj\\pythonchart.png` will surely fail.

Comment: Yes I know, I mean what would my script look like? will "rb" still work?

Comment: If you are using Linux, and you change the path in the `open()` statement, then the script I posted will work correctly for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should try opening in binary mode `open('filename', 'rb').read()`

Comment: This does absolutely nothing unless OP is on Windows.

Comment: From the question's comments, we can infer that OP *is* on Windows.