# How to know when stdin is empty if it contains EOF?

Tags: python, stdin, cat

In an attempt to create a simple `cat` clone in python,

```
sys.stdout.write(sys.stdin.read())
```

I noticed that this fails horribly for binary files (i.e. `python cat.py < binaryfile > supposed_copy`) containing the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> [EOF / substitude character 0x1a](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character), since that seems to cause `read()` to consider its work done. I cannot simply loop over the code forever to circumvent this, since obviously at some point `stdin.read()` will wait until new input is provided, which once the true end of input is reached won't ever happen.

So, how can this be fixed, i.e.

- How to know when the file redirected to `stdin` is fully read, or
- how to properly handle this?

Comment: Sounds like you are opening the file as text instead of binary.  Can you show the `open` statement please?

Comment: @cdarke: Python opens stdin and stdout for you...

Comment: This probably gives you the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850893/reading-binary-data-from-stdin

Comment: OK, I misunderstood.  You probably want to reopen stdin as binary then, but really stdin and stdout are not suitable for binary files.

Comment: @cdarke: At least, stdin and stdout are not suitable for binary files on Windows. :)

Comment: I’d just like to chime in that this is a very non-Python-specific problem. For instance, there is **no** standards compliant, platform independent way to achieve this in C++.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Good point, though doesn't C++ have a similar `msvcrt.setmode`?

Comment: As a side-note, I didn't really want to reimplement `cat`, but rather a `git` clean/smudge filter for a binary format, where git relies on `stdin/stdout`

Comment: @Tobias No. *Windows* libraries have `_setmode`, which you can call on the associated C file handle (and, as an implementation detail, the C++ streams on Windows will use that). However, that’s then of course Windows specific, and relies on non-standardised behaviour of the streams. In practice this means it can be achieved, but requires platform- and compiler specific code.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I keep forgetting how complicated non-Python is :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2374507/321973):

```
if sys.platform == "win32":
    import msvcrt
    msvcrt.setmode(sys.stdout.fileno(), os.O_BINARY)
    msvcrt.setmode(sys.stdin.fileno(), os.O_BINARY)
```

Comment: Well, that's a bit simpler than I was expecting. :) OTOH, I guess there's a big demand for this kind of thing, so it makes sense that Microsoft have made it fairly easy.

Comment: @PM2Ring Indeed, though I wonder why Microsoft made this difference to start with. Just that automated CR/LF conversion mades me curse a lot...

Comment: Well, Bill Gates wanted to make MS-DOS different to Unix. And I guess he thought the CRLF and Ctrl-Z things were a good idea at the time. Similar remarks apply to using backslash as a path separator. But discussing these topics can lead to [Religious Wars](http://forums.xkcd.com/viewforum.php?f=40), so I guess I better shut up. :)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to tell Python to open `stdin` and `stdout` in binary mode. You can do this with the `-u` option. Eg

```
python -u cat.py < binaryfile > supposed_copy
```

Note that this will make `stdin` and `stdout` unbuffered.

Comment: That's working great, can the effect of `-u` be achieved from within Python code?

Comment: @TobiasKienzler: Probably not, since those files are already opened when they get passed to your script. There _might_ be some Windows magic that can alter the mode of a stream that's already open, but if so, accessing it from Python would require using something like `ctypes` (which lets you call functions in DLLs). But anyway, stdin and stdout are special, and usually connected to a terminal, so even if your OS lets you change modes of normal files it might be touchy about stdin & stdout. :) (FWIW, I don't know much about Windows).

Comment: Some Windows magic indeed: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28673339/321973 So much for transparent portability :/

Comment: Fortunately. This btw also fixes any CRLF <-> LF issues that binary files would encounter. Oh Microsoft, why, why, why...

Answer (score 1):

See [Reading binary data from stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850893/reading-binary-data-from-stdin) for an explanation of how to make sure stdin/stdout are opened as binary.

Comment: Thanks, indeed [one answer there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4160894/321973) solves this, though it wouldn't harm to mention that here ;) Anyway, I found [a similar answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28673339/321973)