# Python Piping between arecord and aplay

Tags: python, pipe, stdout, stdin, alsa

I want to record voice, process it, than play it on the fly. The code below should describe more.

```
arecord -D plughw:USER -f S16_LE -t raw | python my_app.py | aplay -D plughw:USER -f S16_LE
```

I was able to capture input from `arecord` for `my_app.py` by using `raw_input()`. Now, I have problem on how to send `my_app.py` output to `aplay`.

I've tried using `subprocess` inside `my_app.py` to run `aplay`,

```
cmdPlay = 'aplay -D plughw:USER -f S16_LE'
p = subprocess.Popen(
    cmdPlay,
    stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
    stdin = subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr = subprocess.PIPE,
    shell = True
)
p.communicate(input=dataHex.decode('hex'))
```

But, I heard no voice played on speaker.

So, **how do you piping between python app and other processes (as input and output)?**
n.b.: Please also suggest a better method, if any, than `raw_input()` for capture data from arecord.

Comment: Why don't you just write the data to `stdout`?

Comment: @CL., I've tried with `sys.stdout.write(data)`, but it not received by the `aplay`. Could you provide with an example of your idea? I might just be wrong in using `stdout`. thanks

Comment: see [Python 2.x - Write binary output to stdout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374427/python-2-x-write-binary-output-to-stdout)