# How to print a pdf file to stdout using python?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, pdf, readfile

A correct pdf file has been created by a script (whose output can't be directly written to stdout, unfortunately). Say the file's name is 'myfile.pdf'.

I want to print the exact pdf content to stdout. (No processing in between).

To test this, I have written this short `read_pdf.py` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

with open('myfile.pdf', mode='rb') as pdf_file:
    for line in pdf_file:
        print(str(line))
```

I use the `'rb'` mode because reading this in text mode leads to a `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 10: invalid continuation byte`. So, it doesn't look like there's any other alternative (if text mode doesn't work, then binary mode).

Now of course the problem is that the output consists of `b'blablabla'` lines that cannot be used as a pdf file. To check it, I redirect `read_pdf.py` to a file and try to open it with a pdf viewer and of course it doesn't work:

```
$ ./read_pdf.py > test_output.pdf
$ evince test_output.pdf
Syntax Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
Syntax Error: Couldn't read xref table
Syntax Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
Syntax Error: Couldn't read xref table
```

So, what is the right way to do it? I haven't checked any pdf dedicated library because it doesn't look necessary, I'd like to be able to read and print correct content without importing a pdf library for that.

`chardet.detect(pdf_file.read())` couldn't help (it returned `{'encoding': None, 'confidence': 0.0}`).

EDIT:
* I'm looking for a solution for python3 and for a Linux/Unix system, not windows.
* I need to know how to do this in python because its's actually part of a bigger project entirely written in python

Comment: Any reason you can't just `cat some.pdf`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374427/python-2-x-write-binary-output-to-stdout

Comment: @armandino because it's actually part of a bigger project entirely written in python

Comment: @Robᵩ except this is for python3 and not about Windows. I will add this precisions to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are reading line by line, therefore adding extra carriage returns. I tried and works perfectly on OSX:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

with open('myfile.pdf', mode='rb') as pdf_file:
        print(pdf_file.read())
```

For the sake of completeness, as noted by @zezollo, in Linux the file will still be corrupted using the `print` function, so it is necessary to write directly on the buffer:

```
import sys

with open('myfile.pdf', mode='rb') as pdf_file:
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(pdf_file.read())
```

Comment: This is dead simple, and better than my attempts, but the output is still "enclosed" inside a `b'   '`. The output cannot be read by the pdf viewer. So I have naively tried to print `str(pdf_file.read())[2:-1]` instead. This looks good, but cannot be read by the pdf viewer neither.

Comment: I was expecting to have the same behavior in OSX and Linux, but apparently there is some difference in the print implementation. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is actually to use `sys.stdout.buffer.write()`, instead of `print()`, and in addition to `pdf_file.read()`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys

with open('myfile.pdf', mode='rb') as pdf_file:
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(pdf_file.read())
```